# Couldn't install Cordova CLI

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I do have a lot of trouble to upgrade my Cordova Version to 3.0 on my Macbook
I did everything, what the [manual](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) said: 
when I type this in the Terminal:
    $ sudo npm install -g cordova

I'm asked for my password - but when I try to fill in my pw nothing happens (not even * as placeholders for the letters of my pw show up on the screen)
When I push Enter then, I get the following:
    sudo: npm: command not found

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you installed node first ??

Comment: Have you Node.js installed in your sistem?

Comment: yes, long while ago - it says v0.10.32 when I type node -v in the Terminal